# Accessing a class/method from another program in Python

Tags: python, python-2.3

I have a program (`blackjack.py`) and it accesses another program's (`cards.py` and `games.py`) within its code. Most of this is from a book, so I'm having trouble understanding how it works.

Heres the code for `cards.py`:

```
class Card(object):
    """ A playing card. """
    RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
             "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
    SUITS = ["c", "d", "h", "s"]
    def __init__(self, rank, suit, face_up = True):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.is_face_up = face_up

    def __str__(self):
        if self.is_face_up:
            rep = self.rank + self.suit
        else:
            rep = "XX"
        return rep

    def flip(self):
        self.is_face_up = not self.is_face_up


class Hand(object):
    """ A Hand of playing cards. """
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def __str__(self):
        if self.cards:
            rep = ""
            for card in self.cards:
                rep += str(card) + "\t"
        else:
            rep = "<empty>"
        return rep

    def clear(self):
        self.cards = []

    def add(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def give(self, card, other_hand):
        self.cards.remove(card)
        other_hand.add(card)


class Deck(Hand):
    """ A deck of playing cards. """
    def populate(self):
        for suit in Card.SUITS:
            for rank in Card.RANKS:
                self.add(Card(rank, suit))

    def shuffle(self):
        import random
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self, hands, per_hand = 1):
        for round in range(per_hand):
            for hand in hands:
                if self.cards:
                    top_card = self.cards[0]
                    self.give(top_card, hand)
                else:
                    print "Can't continue deal. Out of cards!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "This is a module with classes for playing cards."
    raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

I'm writing an error check for the `blackjack.py` and I need to gather the number of cards that have been used so far. I think I can do that by accessing the number of values in `cards[]`. The problem is, I am not sure on how to do that.

This is all in theory though. I will include the `blackjack.py' code as well, so you all can see what I am trying to do, and help me determine if my logic is flawed.

`blackjack.py` [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5i8xr886hg5wcaj/blackjack_Attempt_3.py)

Any and all input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not entirely clear on your intended structure here, you have a couple of options.

First, in order to use any functions or classes from `cards.py` in your `blackjack.py` module, you can use the `import` statement to import them.  There are two styles of doing this:

```
# blackjack.py
import cards
```

Would give you access to everything in the `cards` module, and you'd call each function/class by prefacing it with `cards.<name>`.  So, if you wanted to initialize an instance of the `Deck` class,

```
# blackjack.py
import cards
mydeck = cards.Deck()
```

The other way is the `from <X> import <Y>`, which gives you access to the functions and classes without having to add the prefix.  Example:

```
# blackjack.py
from cards import Deck  # or, to import everything, "from cards import *"
mydeck = Deck()
```

Either of these methods would give you an instance of the `cards.Deck` class.

#### Option 0

You can already tell this within your `Deck` class, since it subclasses from `Hand`, so every time you `give` a card it's taking out out of the `Deck`'s `cards` attribute.  Thus, the number of cards given out would simply be:

```
class Deck(Hand):
    # ...
    def number_cards_used(self):
         return 52 - len(self.cards)
```

Alternatively, if you can't edit `cards.py`, you can simply get the number of cards left from your given `Deck` by:

```
# blackjack.py
def get_number_cards_used_from_deck(deck):
    return 52 - len(deck.cards)
```

In use:

```
# blackjack.py
import cards
mydeck = cards.Deck()
# ...
# Do other operations with deck
# ...
cards_used = get_number_cards_used_from_deck(mydeck)
```

#### Option 1

If you can isolate all of and only those hands being played simultaneously, you can implement a method `card_count`:

```
class Hand(object):
   # ...
   # other code
   # ....

   def card_count(self):
       return len(self.cards)
```

Then, if you have a list of all the hands, for example, you could do something like:

```
sum(map(lambda h: h.card_count(), list_of_hands))
```

#### Option 2

Within your `Deck` class, since it subclasses `Hand`, you could simply keep another running list of the cards that have been given out that would often be refreshed.  This would look like:

```
class Deck(Hand):
    # ...
    # other code
    # ...

    def __init__(self):
        self.populate()
        self.used_cards = []

    def give(self, card, other_hand):
        self.used_cards.append(card)
        super(Deck, self).give(card, other_hand)

    def number_cards_used(self):
        return len(self.used_cards)
```

There are other methods, of course.

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this _without_ adding to `cards.py`? I thought of something similar as well. I think that's what I am supposed to do anyway. I was asking how to use what I have in `cards.py` and `blackjack.py` to gather how many cards were left / in use. I have no idea how to access the `cards.py` file, and thought that by accessing it, I could somehow get the number of cards left. Can I?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "accessing" `cards.py`.  You don't have to edit `cards.py` to use option 0--given a `Deck()` initialized in variable `mydeck`, you could at any time do `52 - len(mydeck.cards)` to find out how many cards were used.  IS that what you mean?

Comment: What I mean by "accessing" is exactly how it sounds. How do I _use_ a method or class from `cards.py` in `blackjack.py`? How would I get a `Deck()` initialized variable?

Comment: No need to get all agitated.  "Accessing" isn't a technical term, and as such is ill-defined.  Using a method or class from `cards.py` can be done using the `import` statement, and it was not made clear earlier that that was your question.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I'm not agitated. That wasn't meant in a sarcastic manner, I'm sorry you saw it as such; that's not what I intended. I'm new to all this method and class lingo; I've never had to use either of them. Anyway thank you for your help so far, I think I am getting closer. I have `cards.py` imported properly, but the rest still doesn't seem to work as I want it to. I have a function (or what I believe is a function) at the very top of the page that goes something like:

    `myDeck = cards.Deck()`

    `def get_num_cards(myDeck):`
        `return 52 - len(myDeck.cards)`

Comment: Ok, that did not format the way I wished, but I hope you get the general idea. But every time I call that function(or method?) it returns 52. So I guess I am closer, but not yet there.

Comment: Well, that means that `myDeck.cards` right now has no cards in it at all.  That's because when you're just doing `myDeck = cards.Deck()`, the `Deck` class starts of with `self.cards = []`.  You have to do `myDeck = cards.Deck()`, and then call the method `myDeck.populate()` in order to actually populate `myDeck.cards` with all of the cards.  If you do that, and then try calling `get_num_cards(myDeck)`, you'll probably find it returns `0`.

Comment: I thought that it would already call the `populate()` in normal gameplay. I'll look through it and try it.

Comment: It won't.  When you instantiate a class, the `__init__` method is called upon instantiation, but the `Deck` class you've provided in `cards.py` does not have an `__init__` method.  If you look at __Option 2__ that I provided, you'll see that I created an `__init__` method for `Deck` that calls `self.populate()`, so that upon creating any `Deck`, `Deck.cards` would automatically be populated.  In the code you provided above, it won't be.

Comment: Right at the beginning of the `BJ_Game` class in the `__init__` method it calls `self.deck.populate`. Under that I tried adding `numCards = len(self.deck)` but it says "TypeError: len() of unsized object".

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm making this a pain, or more complicated than it should be, I truly am.

Comment: Okay, well looking at your `BJ_Game` code, it does call `self.deck.populate`, so it should populate then.  You shouldn't add `numCards = len(self.deck)` but you need to add `numCards = len(self.deck.cards)`.  Alternatively, you could add somewhere in one of the deck classes `def __len__(self):  return len(self.cards)` or something along those lines.

Comment: It works! Haha! Ok, well I have that all sorted out and working. Then at each `play()` method, I have it checking if `numCards` is less than or equal to `numPlayers * 7`. If it is less I have it doing `self.deck = BJ_Deck()`
        `self.deck.populate()`
        `numCards = len(self.deck.cards)`
        `self.deck.shuffle()`

Comment: Sorry, keep pressing enter on accident and forgetting shift + enter. Anyway, it doesn't seem to reset the deck or the count like it should? Any idea why? I'm sure the `numCards` works properly, I checked it with strategically placed `print` statements. Just not sure why it won't start the deck over and shuffle it.

Comment: You should create a new question for that, as it's beyond the scope of this one.  Also, this comment thread has really gone on too long as it is, anyway.

Comment: Haha ok. Well thanks for your help man. Got it working anyway.